# How to fix 'Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIColor''

Tags: swift

As I just start learning programming, it shows the following errors that my code have.

Use of undeclared type 'NSObect'
Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIColor'
Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIColor'

Could someone please point my error here and correct back my code? Thankssss if you could help:)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
    [NSObect:AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame:
        UIScreen.main.bounds)

    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let myTabBar = UITabBarController()

    myTabBar.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let mainViewController = ViewController()
    mainViewController.tabBarItem =
        UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .favorites, tag: 100)

    let articleViewController = ArticleViewController()
    articleViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
```

Comment: Apart from the (partial) old Swift 2 code `NSObect` is a typo, it's `NSObject`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using old code so replace:

```
self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

with

```
self.window!.backgroundColor = .white
```

And Replace:

```
myTabBar.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

with

```
myTabBar.tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: Thanks very much and how about this code?
        [NSObect:AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

Error: Use of undeclared type 'NSObect'

Comment: is it necessary to declare something so as to make it work? Thank you

Comment: its now replaced with `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` and you need to update it. Looks like you are opening an old project.

Comment: but then the new error comes out..
Invalid redeclaration of 'application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)'
How could I fix it to make it work?

Comment: Buddy you need to make some reachers about errors you are getting because there is tons of examples already exists.. :)

Comment: I recommend to simplify your code with .white, instead of UIColor.white

Comment: I kept is basic so OP can understand the changes. @EvgeniyKleban

Comment: I think I have solved.. And thanks for you guys helping .. :)

Comment: Happy to help you. And don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you. :)